# Does SOAP support canceling a call?

Tags: soap, request-cancelling

When using the SOAP protocol, is it possible to cancel a pending remote function call using SOAP?

I see three different situations:

- A) Making a request to a service that takes a long time to complete. For example, when copying directory containing a lot of files, can the file copy loop be canceled?
- B) Making a request that returns a long list. For example, when querying a big in-memory list of user names, can the transmission of this list-response be canceled?
- C) Canceling a call that is still on the internal call queue; in other words, before the server has begun processing it. This can happen when issuing a lot of asynchronous calls in a short time.

Answer (score 3):

From the client's point of view, cancelling a synchronous (request-response) SOAP call is the same as for any other HTTP call - just disconnect and stop listening for the response. A well written server will check whether the client is still connected before proceeding with lengthy operations (e.g. in .NET the server would check [IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx)) and should cancel the operation if not.

One-way calls cannot be cancelled in this manner however, because you've already sent the payload and disconnected. Cancellation of one-way calls would require an explicit call to some sort of cancellation method on the SOAP service, which it would have to explicitly support.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you make the assumption that there will be made a new connection for each call. Doesn't that hurt performance very badly?